# Difference between keep-indexed and map-indexed?

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between [`map-indexed`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed) and [`keep-indexed`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep-indexed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

map-indexed is like map, except that the index of each element in the coll is passed as the first arg to the function that map-indexed takes, and the element is passed as the second arg to the function.

So

```
(map-indexed + [1 2 3 4]) ;=> ((+ 0 1) (+ 1 2) (+ 2 3) (+ 3 4)) => (1 3 5 7)
```

keep-indexed works the same way as map-indexed with the difference that if (f index value) returns nil, it is not included in the resulting seq.

So for example:

```
(keep-indexed #(and %1 %2) [1 2 3 nil 4]) ;;=> (1 2 3 4)
```

You can think of keep-indexed as map-indexed wrapped in filter as follows:

```
(filter (complement nil?) (map-indexed f coll))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Keep-indexed` will keep the result of `fn` if result is not nil

```
(keep-indexed #(if (odd? %1) %2) [:a :b :c :d :e])
;;(:b :d)
```

`map-indexed` will keep all result of applying `fn` to coll regardless return value is nil or not

```
(map-indexed #(if (odd? %1) %2) [:a :b :c :d :e])
;; (nil :b nil :d nil)
```